# 403 forbidden and CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

```
import requests
import json
headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.87 Safari/537.36'}
post_data={"q":"","filters":{"sizes":["Large","MNE"],"sectors":[18],"countries":[228],"regions":["Northern America"],"years":[2015],"types":[]},"page":1}


with requests.Session() as s:
    for_cookies=s.get('http://database.globalreporting.org/search')
    # print(for_cookies.content)
    p = s.post('http://database.globalreporting.org/search/ajax/',data=json.dumps(post_data), headers=headers)
    print(p.content)
```

My chrome can visit the website but my code cannot. How to make my code able to visit the website?
[image]

Comment: You are not sending csrf token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add CSRF token value to your headers:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    for_cookies=s.get('http://database.globalreporting.org/search')

    headers =  
    {'X-CSRFToken': for_cookies.headers['Set-Cookie'].split('=')[1].split(';')[0],
    'Referer': 'http://database.globalreporting.org/search/',
    'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'}

    p = s.post('http://database.globalreporting.org/search/ajax/',data=json.dumps(post_data), headers=headers)
    print(p.content)
```

Try this code and let me know in case of any issues

Answer (score 2):

I have included the csrf token and tried to call it. But I think the Django website must have used,

```
if not request.is_ajax():
    return HttpResponse('Only ajax request')
```

Because I tried the code,

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as client:
    for_cookies=client.get('http://database.globalreporting.org/search')
    csrf = client.cookies['csrftoken']
    print csrf
    post_data={"csrfmiddlewaretoken": csrf, "q":"","filters":{"sizes":["Large","MNE"],"sectors":[18],"countries":[228],"regions":["Northern America"],"years":[2015],"types":[]},"page":1}
    r = client.post('http://database.globalreporting.org/search/ajax/', data=post_data, headers=dict(Referer='http://database.globalreporting.org/search'))
    print r.text
```

The response I get is

```
YrZa9IIoFJZyXqeRXZnZ57s3vaoCUCul
Only ajax request
```

In general you have to use csrf token in these cases. But we can configure whether to use ajax only.

Hope my answer helps you.